# Activemerchant SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, activemerchant

I'm getting this error when creating new Paypal notification with active merchant

```
class PaymentNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  include ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations

  protect_from_forgery except: :create

  def create
    notify = Paypal::Notification.new(request.raw_post)
```

> A OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError occurred in payment_notifications#create:
>   SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
>   certificate verify failed
>   /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in
>   `connect'

- Activemerchant version: 1.47.0
- Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails version: 3.2.16
- Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Openssl version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is a solution to this problem: https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Comment: Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, there's not enough information to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things:

1. make sure your certificates are up to date on your machine.
2. this has gotten me around this error before: https://github.com/stevegraham/certified

Good luck. Hope this helps.